# JAVA programming confusion

Tags: java

The problem: Using a switch case, write a menu driven program to convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa for incorrect option.

I have proceeded the problem as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class convert {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
        int ch;
        double fah, cel;
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        System.out.println("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice");
        ch = Sc.nextInt();
        switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("enter Fahrenheit values");
            fah = Sc.nextDouble();
            cel = 5.0 / 9.0 * (fah - 32.0);
            System.out.println("Celsius =" + cel);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("enter Celsius values");
            fah = Sc.nextDouble();
            cel = 1.8 * (fah + 32.0);
            System.out.println("Fahrenheit=" + cel);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("vice versa.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is my method correct? Please help.

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: The problem is not with the switch statement, the problem is that the code doesn't compile.  You need to write this in Java.  It looks like you have written this in Word, or WordPad or on a mobile.  I suggest using an IDE.

Comment: You are receiving downvotes because ... there is no clear problem statement in your question; and besides that: the title is absolutely useless.

Comment: Jägermeister said it all. If you don't want  your question to be closed, please clarify what your actual problem is, once your code compiles. And please, **please**, format your code.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working Fine. No issues in this code. only issue is formatting issue.

See the below code:

```
 int ch;
   double fah, cel; 
   Scanner Sc= new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("Menu");
   System.out.println("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
   System.out.println("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
   System.out.println("Enter your choice");
   ch= Sc.nextInt();
   switch (ch)
   {
   case 1: System.out.println("enter Fahrenheit values");
   fah= Sc. nextDouble();
   cel=  5.0/9.0*(fah-32.0);
   System.out.println("Celsius ="+cel);
   break;
   case 2 : System.out.println("enter Celsius values");
   fah= Sc. nextDouble();
   cel=1.8*(fah+32.0);
   System.out.println("Fahrenheit="+cel);
   break;
   default : System.out.println( "vice versa.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatted and Made compilable... Next time use an IDE for coding...

```
 import java. io.*;
import java. util.*;

class Main00
{
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
{
int ch;
double fah, cel; 

Scanner Sc= new Scanner (System. in);
System.out.println("MENU");
System.out.println("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
System.out.println("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
System.out.println("Enter your choice");
ch= Sc.nextInt();
switch (ch)
{
case 1: System.out.print("enter Fahrenheit values");
fah= Sc. nextDouble();
cel=  5.0/9.0*(fah-32.0);
System.out.println("Celsius ="+cel);
break;
case 2 : System.out.print("enter Celsius values");
fah= Sc. nextDouble();
cel=1.8*(fah+32.0);
System.out.println("Fahrenheit="+cel);
break;
default : System.out.println( "vice versa.");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please use tabs. This code is hardly readable and the formatting is inconsistent. The code from the question works fine, you just made it unreadable. Please next time don't be rude to the person who asks the question.